# Manage state for 2 components same time vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am really new to vue and vuex and trying to learn vue.
I have a problem and having some hard time figuring it out.
I am trying to make a website like stack overflow for training purpose. There is a home page containing feed component, the feed component contains the feed with the top voted answer within.

```
<div v-if="isLoaded" class="content__child-wrapper">
  <template v-if="this.pagination.total > 0">
    <template v-for="(question, index) in questions">
      <QuestionFeed :key="question.id" :question="question" :answer=(question.qa_answers && question.qa_answers.length > 0)? true: false" />
      <InFeedSuggestions :key="question.id + '_' + index" v-if="index == 0"/>
    </template>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <InFeedSuggestions :isQuestionAvail="false" class="mb-20" />
  </template>
</div>
```

I am showing 5 feeds and a load more button to load more feed with a most voted answer. There is also a section right after the first feed that show 3 feeds that are newly inserted and are not being answered yet.
Coming to the problem.
I want to load all the feeds from vuex and store it in state and then display them on the home page but as there are 2 different part one is feed with an answer which is called from a different API call and one is without answer that is being called from different API request how should I manage them in the state. should I make different state for them both and have different actions for the 2 states or there is a better way.

Comment: either one state or two state is fine. if one state, you have to use one flag to indicate one element is answered or not. if two state, you may have to merge two states when filter or sort. it is one choice for left hand or right hand.

Comment: **Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application** ... so basically you try to centralize